# Evaluation of $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin ^{ -1 }{ x } -\tan ^{ -1 }{ x } }{ { x }^{ 3 } } } \quad $ without using L'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

My aim is to evaluate the following limit

> $\displaystyle\lim _{ x\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \sin ^{ -1 }{ x } -\tan ^{ -1 }{ x }  }{ { x }^{ 3 } }  } \quad$

which evaluates to $\frac{1}{2}$ after using L'Hospital rule for rather $5$ steps, which of course is a tedious task. Could anyone suggest some shorter and elegant methods for evaluating this limit?

Thanks.

Comment: Using $\arcsin'(x) = (1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ and $\arctan'(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1}$ and the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) it's straight forward to expand these functions in a power-series.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of the expansions of inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: btw to derive the expression for the derivatives above you can consider $\arctan(\tan(x)) = x$, take the derivative and express the result in terms of $y = \tan(x)$. Similar for other trigonometric functions.

Comment: Write numerator as $-(x-\sin^{-1}x)+(x-\tan^{-1}x)$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Maclaurin series:

$$\arcsin x-\arctan x=x+\frac16x^3+\frac3{40}x^5+\ldots-\left(x-\frac13x^3+\frac15x^5-\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac12x^3+\mathcal O(x^5)$$

so

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arcsin x-\arctan x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12x^3+\mathcal O(x^5)}{x^3}=\frac12$$

Comment: The use of series expansion is equivalent to the use of l'Hopital rule.

Comment: @CesarEo  No, it's not...but it is very similar, true. Yet the OP did not want to avoid derivatives and L'Hospital, but rather to have a faster, simpler method to evaluate that limit.

Answer (score 7):

We have

$$
\sin(\arcsin(x)-\arctan(x))=\frac{x(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\arcsin(x)-\arctan(x)}{x^3}\right)\equiv \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x)-\arctan(x))}{\sin(x^3)}\right)
$$

then

$$
\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x)-\arctan(x))}{\sin(x^3)} = \frac{x^3(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{x^2\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin(x^3)} = \left(\frac{x^3}{\sin(x^3)}\right)\frac{x^2}{x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$

then

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin(\arcsin(x)-\arctan(x))}{x^3}\right)\equiv\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^3}{\sin(x^3)}\right)\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})\sqrt{1+x^2}} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: Very nice and novel argument. +1 I would have instead written $\arcsin x-\arctan x=\arcsin(\dots) $.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy!

Lets start by noting that $$arcsin(x)=x+x^3/6+3x^5/40+...$$
Next $$arctan(x)=x-x^3/3+x^5/5-...$$
When this is substituted in you limit equation above we have for the numerator:
$$x^3/2-x^5/8 ...$$
When this is divided by $x^3$ and we pass to the limit we get the simple result of 1/2.

Comment: This is same answer as above...why?