# Solve $\lim_{x→0} \frac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Prove that $$\lim_{x→0} \frac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$
\lim_{x→0} \frac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}=\lim_{x→0} \frac{\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}
\\
=\lim_{x→0} \frac{\tan^{-1}\bigg[\frac{\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-x}{1+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\bigg]}{x^3}
=\lim_{x→0} \frac{\tan^{-1}\bigg[\frac{x(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})}{\sqrt{1-x^2}+x^2}\bigg]}{x^3}\\
\text{since, }\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}>-1
$$

I think I am getting stuck here, do not really see how to proceed further with the steps.

**Note:** I don't want to use L'Hospital's rule as I 'd like to solve it without using the derivatives of $\sin^{-1}x$ and $\tan^{-1}x$.

Comment: In the last equation, the denominator should be $\sqrt{ 1 - x^2} + x^2$.

Comment: For the numerator, use $x( 1 - \sqrt{ 1 - x^2 } ) = x ( 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + o( x^2 )) = \frac{1}{2} x^3 + o( x^3) $.

Comment: There is also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760569/find-the-limit-limit-x-tends-to-zero-arcsinx-arctanx-x3) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791367/evaluation-of-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frac-sin-1-x-tan-1).

Comment: Generally speaking, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(x%5Cright)-%5Ctan%5E%7B-1%7D%5Cleft(x%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%5E3%7D%24&p=1) works really well to find such duplicates.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thanks for mentioning, is difficult to actually find it by googling i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^{3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}{x^{3}}\cdot\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}{x^{3}}\cdot 1\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x)\cos(\tan^{-1}x)-\cos(\sin^{-1}x)\sin(\tan^{-1}x)}{x^{3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{x\cdot\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}}{x^{3}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{2}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1-(1-x^{2})}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Personally I don't like this notation$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}{x^{3}}\cdot\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x)}{x^{3}}\cdot 1$$

Comment: Sorry maybe it is trivial but I don't get this step $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\cdot\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{x^{2}}\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1-(1-x^{2})}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$

Comment: The $1/\sqrt{1+x^{2}}$ goes to $1$, so just omit it. For the rest, multiply it with the conjugate $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, I din't get the $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}$ term but it is not essential. This seems a very good way to prove this limit.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You can get rid of the $\arctan$ functions as

$$\tan(a-b)=\frac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}.$$ If $a$ and $b$ tend to zero, the denominator can be ignored, and

$$\frac{\tan(a-b)}{a-b}$$ tends to $1$.

Then

$$\frac x{x^3\sqrt{1-x^2}}-\frac x{x^3}=\frac 1{x^2\sqrt{1-x^2}}(1-\sqrt{1-x^2})=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you are not allowed to use Taylor’s series, we can assume that the limits as $x\to 0$

$$\frac{\tan^{-1}x-x}{x^3}=L_1\quad \frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{x^3}=L_2$$

exists and show by algebraic manipulation that they are equal to $L_1=-\frac13$ and $L_2=\frac16$.

Then we can use these results to find the limit, indeed

$$\frac{\sin^{-1}x-\tan^{-1}x}{x^3}=\frac{\sin^{-1}x-x}{x^3}-\frac{\tan^{-1}x-x}{x^3} \to \frac16+\frac13=\frac12$$

Refer also to

- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

Answer (score -2):

**hint**

Sorry, i understood that $\sin^{-1}(x)$ means $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ instead of $\arcsin(x)$.

Comment: How is it possible?

Comment: How to transform inverse trig functions into trig functions ?

Comment: @ss1729 You mean $ \arcsin $.

Comment: yes indeed !! . $\tan^{-1}x\equiv \arctan x$